# Call a bash script from python with a desired string

Tags: python, bash, file, shadow

I have a python script which gets the password of a user from /etc/shadow for a project I’m doing. Let’s say I get the password in the python script as “jumbo”. So, how would I go about calling the bash script while within the python script? It has to be in a manner where the password, “jumbo”, is passed to the bash script to be used.

The reason I’m passing it to a bash script is because I then need to log into a user, say “worker”, with that password while in the bash script (instead of at the command line obviously) to be automatically logged into the “worker” account when the bash script finishes executing and it returns to the python script to continue the rest of the python code that’s after the bash script call.

Edit: I’m confused how to call the bash script in python and am also confused how to “catch” the string in the bash script.

Comment: try `subprocess.run`

Comment: I’ll look into this. I’m more confused how to “catch” the string in the bash script

Comment: Approve the answer to mark the question as an answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a script with arguments, you can use `check_call` function:

```py
from subprocess import check_call

rc = check_call("./file.sh %s %s %s" % (agr1, str(arg2), arg3), shell=True)
```

**remember** to convert the args to string before passing, using str(arg).

Comment: And how would you go about receiving the string In the bash script? Also, from just doing the above that you provided, can the bash script access the password string from the python script?

Comment: Ah that is much more helpful! And how would I catch that in the bash script (if that’s what I need to do).. or can you just access them?

Comment: Receive it as any command-line argument, take a look at the "Argument" section in this documentation: https://devhints.io/bash

Comment: Long story short, the first argument will be accessed by using ```$1``` and the second one will be ```$2``` and so on.

Comment: I find that, when using the various `subprocess` functions, it is always better to pass the command as a list of strings, rather than as a string. This means you can pass arguments with arbitrary contents, including spaces and various punctuation, without having to worry about how they will be interpreted.

Comment: you should escape those shell strings https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html